# Angular 2 after update I get this error: Cannot read property 'zone' of undefined

Tags: angular, zone

I just updated angular 2 from beta 9 to beta 11 (or beta 10) and now I get this error in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zone' of undefined` in `angular2-polyfills.js:142` without changing anything to code.

The line in `angular2-polyfills.js:142` where console report the error is:

```
task.zone.cancelTask(task);
```

I am using plain js.

In index.html I include this 4 js files:

```
<script src="libs/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.11/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.11/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.11/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>
```

And all ngZone related code that I use is to make a method of a class accesible from external js.

```
window.PushService = {
            onCallFromOutside: this.onCallFromOutside.bind(this),
            zone: _ngZone
        };
```

Also I try to comment all code where I use ngZone and the error is still here.

What is related to and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there are some problems on beta11 regarding Zones. See the message on the angular.io website (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/):

> The current beta.11 release has known bugs relating to significant changes to the zones subsystem. All apps will report an error to the console:
>
> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zone' of undefined
> ```
>
> The app will run unimpeded but it is disconcerting. We hope to have this and other bugs repaired by beta.12. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7660, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7652

Answer (score 2):

I changed lite-server to live-server and the error is gone. Besides, with lite-server updates on the app did not cause page refresh, with live-server page refreshes automatically.

Comment: I don't use any of lite-server or live-server. I use angular2 in a phonegap app. I will wait for next version and hope it will be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: this was helpfull while running locally inside node. it is mentioned also here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7652

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that in 2.0.0-beta.12 the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have updated to angular2@2.0.0-beta.12, make sure you have updated your zone.js@^0.6.6, and I can confirm once you have updated those dependencies zone.js error will disappear. Hopefully this can be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

As for me (i am  using latest Angular CLI)
impoting zone in `main.ts` helps

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// here
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```